# Nginx fastcgi problems with django (double slashes in url?)

Tags: nginx, python, fastcgi, django, url-routing

I'm deploying my first django app. I'm familiar with nginx and fastcgi from deploying php-fpm. I can't get python to recognize the urls. I'm also at a loss on how to debug this further. I'd welcome solutions to this problem and tips on debugging fastcgi problems.

Currently I get a 404 page regardless of the url and for some reason a double slash
For http://www.site.com/admin/

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.site.com/admin//
```

My urls.py from the debug output - which work in the dev server.

```
Using the URLconf defined in ahrlty.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^listings/
^admin/
^accounts/login/$
^accounts/logout/$
```

my nginx config

```
server {
       listen   80;
       server_name  beta.ahrlty.com;
       access_log  /home/ahrlty/ahrlty/logs/access.log;
       error_log  /home/ahrlty/ahrlty/logs/error.log;

       location /static/ {
               alias  /home/ahrlty/ahrlty/ahrlty/static/;
               break;
       }

       location /media/ {
               alias /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
               break;
       }

       location / {
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001;
               break;
       }
}
```

and my fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

And lastly I'm running fastcgi from the commandline with django's manage.py.

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8080 pidfile=mysite.pid minspare=4 maxspare=30 daemonize=false
```

I'm having a hard time debugging this one. Does anything jump out at anybody?

**Notes**

- nginx version: nginx/0.7.62
- Django svn trunk rev 13013

Comment: Is there anything I can add to make this a better question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe have a look at the django documentation at http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined.
the solution for my smiliar problems (but with lighttpd) was putting

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=""
```

in my settings.py. also give

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME="/"
```

a try!

Comment: You were both right, but you told me why.

Thanks to both AgentK and lazerscience!

Answer (score 2):

I know that leaving in SCRIPT_NAME gave me all sorts of problems.

My fastcgi_params in production and testing are:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Everything else is pretty much identical.

Answer (score 2):

I just remove string

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
```

from my nginx config file, and always start working.

(nginx 0.7.65, Django 1.4)